# Asp.net Mvc. Error during execution https request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I put the project to the server, get error - 500 internal server error. On local machine everything works fine. Can anybody help me? Here is my code:
    `
    string path = "xxx.p12";
    string path2 = "xxx.crt";

```
X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + path), "",      X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + path2));
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Add(certificate1);
certificates.Add(certificate2);
X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri); 
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "Post";
request.Timeout = 1000;

byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

request.Proxy = null;

request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
XmlDocument doc = null;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd()); 
}
```

`

Comment: Is that the only error you are receiving?  Can you run your project on the server itself?  Typically when you run the project on the server, the error is more descriptive.